# Difference Between Compose and Comprise

Tags: meaning, word-difference

What is the difference between "compose" and "comprise"?

I try to avoid the use of comprise and compose when I am using English language at all costs as I just cannot seem to use them correctly.

Can anyone explain their use?

Comment: Mick's Dirty Tricks #42: Learn to use *compose* and forget about *comprise*.

Comment: What that means @Mick

Comment: It means that _comprise_ is not used all that often outside of technical contexts. And here's another good trick: [don't accept an answer a mere 20 minutes after you ask a question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: Roger that Sir ;-)

Comment: I was being facetious. If you learn how to arrange your sentences so that you can always use *compose*, you won't need to worry about having to learn how to use *comprise*. I never use it, and I do this for a lot of other words. You might call me lazy, but I'd rather know how to use a few words well than a lot of words badly.

Comment: That's helpful and I'll try to implement that

Answer (score 1):

[**Comprise**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprise), *verb*

> - to be made up of (something) : to include or consist of (something)
> - to make up or form (something)
>
> The pizza comprises 10 slices.

[**Compose**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compose), *verb*

> - to come together to form or make (something)
>
> Ten slices compose the pizza.

It's important to remember that the parts or elements ***compose*** the whole, and the whole ***comprises*** the parts or elements.

When to use each one depends on the order in which you say/write the whole and the parts/elements.

That being said, as others have commented on, it is a general rule of thumb to rearrange the sentence so that ***compose*** is always used.

> The pizza is composed of 10 slices.

Comment: I think you've explained the differences fairly well, but it's worth noting that _comprises_ is generally used in [more technical contexts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22comprises%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=115), and you'd be hard pressed to find anyone using that word to describe a pizza the way you did. Moreover, _compose_ is unlikely to be used to describe a pizza as well. These examples may serve a point, but they have a **very** contrived ring to them.

Comment: compose as used above more commonly occurs in the passive: "The pizza was composed of ten pieces" or more likely "The dinner was composed of six courses"